# The buttons and labels in my app just stack on ecachother

Tags: python, android, kivy

im new to kivy and familiar with tkinter but this issue just does not make sense

code in main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.layout import Layout
kivy.require('2.0.0')


def calculate(self, instance):
    try:
        a = float(self.masahat.text)
        self.darsad_value = self.darsad
        if self.darsad_value:
            b = float(self.darsad_value)
            c = a * (b / 100)
            x = (a - c) * 2.7  # Assuming ro is constant
            rounded_x = round(x, 2)
            self.result_label.text = str(rounded_x)
        else:
            self.result_label.text = 'Enter Darsad Value'
    except ValueError:
        self.result_label.text = 'Invalid Input'

def clear(self, instance):
    self.masahat.text = ''
    self.result_label.text = ''
    self.darsad.text = ''



def standard(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'6')


def hosein(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'21')

def akhavan(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'15.84')

def rasoli(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'13')


def bizhani(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'27')

def mohamadi(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'2.5')

def nikoghadam(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'10')

def ayazi(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'19')

def kazemi(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'22')

def hasanzade(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'13.5')

def m_rasoli(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'2.5')

def karimi(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'2.5')

def darbahani(self):
    self.darsad.delete(0,'end')
    self.darsad.insert(0,'22')


def set_darsad(self, value):
    self.darsad.text = str(value)


class MyRoot(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()



class AluminiumMass(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AluminiumMass().run()
```

code in aluminiummass.kv:

```
<MyRoot>:
    masahat: masahat
    calculate_button: calculate_button
    clear_button: clear_button
    darsad_l: darsad_l
    darsad: darsad
    result_l: result_l
    result_label: result_label
    area: area
    standard: standard
    hosein_momeni: hosein_momeni
    akhavan: akhavan
    rasoli: rasoli
    darbahani: darbahani
    bijani: bijani
    mohammadi: mohammadi
    nikoghadam: nikoghadam
    ayazi: ayazi
    kazemi: kazemi
    hasanzade: hasanzade
    mojtaba: mojtaba
    alikarimi: alikarimi


    GridLayout:
        orientation: "lr-tb"
        cols: 3
        Label: 
            text: "Area:"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id: area
            row: 0
            col: 0

        TextInput: 
            multiline: False 
            font_size: 26
            id: masahat
            row: 1
            col: 0

        Button: 
            text: "Calculate"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id: calculate_button
            on_press: root.calculate()
            row: 4
            col: 0

        Button : 
            text: "AC"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id: clear_button
            on_press: root.clear()
            row: 4
            col: 1

            Label : 
                text: "Darsad:"
                font_size: 26
                bold: True
                id: darsad_l
                row: 2
                col: 0

        TextInput: 
            multiline: False
            font_size: 26
            id: darsad
            row: 3
            col: 0


        Label: 
            text: "Answer: "
            font_size: 26
            halign: "right"
            valign: "middle"
            bold: True
            id: result_l
            row:6
            col:0

        Label: 
            text: ""
            font_size: 26
            halign: "left"
            valign: "middle"
            bold: True
            id: result_label
            row: 6
            col: 1
        
        Button:
            text: "Standard"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:standard
            on_press: root.standard()
            row: 0
            col: 2

        Button:
            text: "Hosein Momeni"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:hosein_momeni
            on_press: root.hosein()
            row: 1
            col: 2

        Button:
            text: "Akhavan"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:akhavan
            on_press: root.akhavan()
            row: 2
            col: 2

        Button:
            text: "Rasoli"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:rasoli
            on_press: root.rasoli()
            row: 3
            col: 2

        Button:
            text: "Darbahani"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:darbahani
            on_press: root.darbahani()
            row: 4
            col: 2

        Button:
            text: "Bijani"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:bijani
            on_press: root.bizhani()
            row: 5
            col: 2

        Button:
            text: "Mohammadi"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:mohammadi
            on_press: root.mohamadi()
            row: 6
            col: 2

        Button:
            text: "Nikoghadam"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:nikoghadam
            on_press: root.nikoghadam()
            row: 0
            col: 3

        Button:
            text: "Ayazi"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:ayazi
            on_press: root.ayazi()
            row:1
            col:3

        Button:
            text: "Kazemi"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:kazemi
            on_press: root.kazemi()
            row: 2
            col: 3

        Button:
            text: "Hasanzade"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:hasanzade
            on_press: root.hasanzade()
            row: 3
            col: 3

        Button:
            text: "Mojtaba Rasoli"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:mojtaba
            on_press: root.m_rasoli()
            row: 4
            col: 3

        Button:
            text: "Ali Karimi"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:alikarimi
            on_press: root.karimi()
            row: 5
            col: 3
```

i have imported and used GridLayout() in my code but i dont know why all the buttons and labels just stack up in one place. can someone please help me? ive been stuck on this issue for a while now

as you can see i have tried row: and col: in aluminiummass.kv
for example

```
        Button:
            text: "Ali Karimi"
            font_size: 26
            bold: True
            id:alikarimi
            on_press: root.karimi()
            row: 5
            col: 3
```

i am using visual studio code and python

Answer (score 0):

You should be seeing the message:

```
[WARNING] <__main__.MyRoot object at 0x7fb7865d7220> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
```

This is the root of your problem. Your `MyRoot` class extends `GridLayout`, so it is a `GridLayout` and must have `cols` or `rows` set. One fix is to just add that to your `kv`:

```
<MyRoot>:
    cols: 1
```